# How to add angular material to asp.net angular template

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, angular-material, angular-material2

I am having a hard time to add angular material to the asp.net core 2.0 Angular template.

I have followed the getting started [here](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) and updated angular -> 4.3.0

**package.json**

```
 {
      "name": "Website",
      "private": true,
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "4.3.0",
        "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.10",
        "@angular/common": "4.3.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "4.3.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.3.0",
        "@angular/core": "4.3.0",
        "@angular/forms": "4.3.0",
        "@angular/http": "4.3.0",
        "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.10",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "4.3.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.3.0",
        "@angular/platform-server": "4.3.0",
        "@angular/router": "4.3.0",
        "@ngtools/webpack": "1.5.0",
        "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
        "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
        "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
        "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
        "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
        "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
        "css": "2.2.1",
        "css-loader": "0.28.4",
        "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
        "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
        "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
        "file-loader": "0.11.2",
        "html-loader": "0.4.5",
        "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
        "jquery": "3.2.1",
        "json-loader": "0.5.4",
        "preboot": "4.5.2",
        "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
        "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
        "rxjs": "5.4.2",
        "style-loader": "0.18.2",
        "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
        "typescript": "2.4.1",
        "url-loader": "0.5.9",
        "webpack": "2.5.1",
        "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
        "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
        "zone.js": "0.8.12"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@types/chai": "4.0.1",
        "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
        "chai": "4.0.2",
        "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
        "karma": "1.7.0",
        "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
        "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
        "karma-webpack": "2.0.3"
      }
    }
```

**app.module.shared.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/navmenu/navmenu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './components/fetchdata/fetchdata.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './components/counter/counter.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        CounterComponent,
        FetchDataComponent,
        HomeComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
            { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ])
    ]
})
export class AppModuleShared {
}
```

**app.module.browser.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule, MdButtonToggleModule } from '@angular/material';
import { AppModuleShared } from './app.module.shared';
import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';


@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppModuleShared,
        MdButtonModule,
        MdCheckboxModule,
        MdButtonToggleModule
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: 'BASE_URL', useFactory: getBaseUrl }
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}

export function getBaseUrl() {
    return document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].href;
```

**counter.component.html**

```
<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>This is a simple example of an Angular component.</p>

<p>Current counts: <strong>{{ currentCount }}</strong></p>

<button (click)="incrementCounter()" md-button>Increments</button>
<md-button-toggle>Toggle me!</md-button-toggle>
```

I have added to modules to the webpack.config.vendor.js and manually run webpack

```
webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js
```

**webpack.config.vendor.js**

```
*omittet code*

const treeShakableModules = [
        '@angular/animations',
        '@angular/common',
        '@angular/compiler',
        '@angular/core',
        '@angular/forms',
        '@angular/http',
        '@angular/platform-browser',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
        '@angular/router',
        '@angular/material',
        '@angular/cdk',
        'zone.js',
    ];
    const nonTreeShakableModules = [
        '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css',
        'bootstrap',
        'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
        'es6-promise',
        'es6-shim',
        'event-source-polyfill',
        'jquery',
    ];

*omittet code*
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Template parse errors: 'md-button-toggle' is not a known element: 1. If 'md-button-toggle' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module. 2. If 'md-button-toggle' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. (" <button (click)="incrementCounter()" md-button>Increments</button> [ERROR ->]<md-button-toggle>Toggle me!</md-button-toggle> "): ng:///AppModuleShared/CounterComponent.html@7:0
vendor.js:39475:34
syntaxError
http://localhost:60756/dist/vendor.js:39475:34
vendor_b1710f1f4a0309d9d6fc</TemplateParser.prototype.parse
http://localhost:60756/dist/vendor.js:50596:19
vendor_b1710f1f4a0309d9d6fc</JitCompiler.prototype._compileTemplate
http://localhost:60756/dist/vendor.js:64748:18
vendor_b1710f1f4a0309d9d6fc</JitCompiler.prototype._compileComponents/<
http://localhost:60756/dist/vendor.js:64668:56
forEach self-hosted:5350:9 vendor_b1710f1f4a0309d9d6fc</JitCompiler.prototype._compileComponents
http://localhost:60756/dist/vendor.js:64668:9
vendor_b1710f1f4a0309d9d6fc</JitCompiler.prototype._compileModuleAndComponents/<
http://localhost:60756/dist/vendor.js:64555:13
then
http://localhost:60756/dist/vendor.js:39464:148
vendor_b1710f1f4a0309d9d6fc</JitCompiler.prototype._compileModuleAndComponents
http://localhost:60756/dist/vendor.js:64554:16
vendor_b1710f1f4a0309d9d6fc</JitCompiler.prototype.compileModuleAsync
http://localhost:60756/dist/vendor.js:64483:32
vendor_b1710f1f4a0309d9d6fc</</PlatformRef_.prototype._bootstrapModuleWithZone
http://localhost:60756/dist/vendor.js:5075:16
vendor_b1710f1f4a0309d9d6fc</</PlatformRef_.prototype.bootstrapModule
http://localhost:60756/dist/vendor.js:5061:16
<anonymous>
boot.browser.ts:23:22
__webpack_require__
bootstrap 75d1053ae484f61423f3:657
fn
bootstrap 75d1053ae484f61423f3:85
<anonymous>
http://localhost:60756/dist/main-client.js:3845:18
__webpack_require__
bootstrap 75d1053ae484f61423f3:657
<anonymous>
bootstrap 75d1053ae484f61423f3:706
<anonymous>
http://localhost:60756/dist/main-client.js:1:11
```

Is this template setup with SystemJS? if so how? (ref.[Appendix Angular Material](http://%20'@angular/material':%20'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material.umd.js'))

Where is this failing?

I haven`t done any other changes to the template.

Comment: which module is `CounterComponent` part of ?

Comment: app.module.shared- Added the code in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add material modules in your `app.module.shared` imports:

```
import { MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule, MdButtonToggleModule } from '@angular/material';

imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
            { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ]),

        MdButtonModule,
        MdCheckboxModule,
        MdButtonToggleModule

    ]
```

Comment: any on this: "Is this template setup with SystemJS? if so how? (ref.Appendix Angular Material)"